# connection error, from python in RCMES vagrant

Tags: python, vagrant

I am trying to test python in RCMES vagrant, and I am getting connection error. can anyone please help to solve this

```
(OCW)vagrant@precise64:~/RCMES/test$ python test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 49, in <module>
    urllib.urlretrieve(FILE_LEADER + MODEL, MODEL)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 98, in urlretrieve
    return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 245, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 213, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 350, in open_http
    h.endheaders(data)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1053, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 897, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 859, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 836, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/home/vagrant/miniconda2/envs/OCW/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 575, in create_connection
    raise err
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno 110] Connection timed out
```